# Merging two array of objects in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object, merge

Input:

```
const name = [{id:1, first_name: "Sade", age:"30"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", age:"40"}];
const ln = [{last_name: "Smith"}, {last_name: "Doe"}];
```

Output:

```
const name = [
  {id:1, first_name: "Sade", last_name: "Smith", age:"30"},
  {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe", age"40"}
];
```

Please help me to get this output in nodejs

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to increase your chances of receiving a positive response to your query please read and consider the points raised in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Spread Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get the desired output:

```js
const name = [{id:1, first_name: "Sade"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon"}];
const lname = [{last_name: "Smith"}, {last_name: "Doe"}];

const output = name.map((o, i) => ({...o, ...lname[i]}));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @MathewWade It will work with your new method as well. Try it.

Comment: but then the ln[] is adding at the end, i want before the age attribute

Comment: @MathewWade Order of properties in an object doesn't matter. If you need properties in a specific order, use array then. See this post for more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order#:~:text=Most%20Browsers%20iterate%20object%20properties,this%20and%20all%20browsers%20comply)

Comment: Is it possible to get output within same array name??